# Restore Qt Creator default layout

Tags: qt, qt-creator

[image: The window I see looks like this]

I am totally new to Qt development. Infact today's my first day! I installed Qt 5.3.1 open source (LGPL license). I was looking around in the Qt Creator and accidentally closed several sub-windows and not able to view the actual code, other list of opened files, etc. But it does load the project and also executes when I click the green 'Run' button. How do I recover the default layout? There is no window layout/View option in the menu. Can't see anything online! Please help...

[image: Window menu]

Comment: Try from menu Window->show slider

Comment: There is no such option in Window. There is 'show sidebar' and others. See the 2nd pic I just added...

Comment: What after pressing `show sidebar` ?

Comment: Views the 'Projects' back. But its still different from default layout. Thanks!

Comment: If everything doesn't help, try reinstalling your qt creator or, if you find them, delete your configuraton file - this will bring back your defualt layout since qt creator thinks this is the first run of it

Comment: @user3755692 I did uninstall and reinstall. But it turned up with the same layout I am having trouble with! I was surprised how!!
Where is this configuration file?

Comment: @learner On my debian system, those files are in /usr/share/qtcreator - if you have such a folder, try deleting it

Comment: @user3755692 I am on Windows 7. I will look around for this file. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @learner Windows always has the problem that the os doesn't know where the files are, but try looking in your %APPDATA%-Variable

Comment: @user3755692 Found it! Deleted it! And it worked! Thanks a lot :) I was quite irritated this editor doesn't come with layout option or any View menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alt+0 will show project tree. Use ctrl+k to open search window.

Regards

Answer (score 7):

Qt Creator creates some files to save the settings. These files are in different location in different operating systems.

On Windows Vista and Windows 7 :

`<drive>:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QtProject` and `<drive>:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\QtProject`

On Linux :

`~/.config/QtProject` and `~/.local/share/data/QtProject/qtcreator`

Try to delete `QtCreator.ini` and many settings including the layout are reset to default  when you reopen Qt Creator.